# Having an error trying to call a systemctl call with the service() method in c++

Tags: c++, system, systemd, systemctl

I am trying to pass a character string of a systemctl command like the one below through the system() method in C++.

```
std::string call = "systemctl --host user@hostName status serviceName.service";

system(call.c_str());
```

However when I make the call I get an error saying that statusserviceName.service is not a valid command. I am dumbfounded by how the space between status and the service file disappears. Does anyone know why this occurs?